# Enable\Disable button "Share" documeny library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

How to enable\disable button "Share" documeny library?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you only want disable and hide “Share” Menu Item in SharePoint Document Library, you should do the following:**

[image]

1.Open your SharePoint Site.

2.Navigate to your document library that you would like to disable and hide the “Share” menu item.

3.Click on the Right Setting Gear icon >> Edit the Page.

4.Click “Add Web Part” >> “Media and Content” >> Add “Script Editor Web Part” >> “Edit Snippet”.

[image]

5.Copy the below CSS, and paste it to your script editor.

```
<style>
.ms-contextmenu-link[title="Shared With"] {
    pointer-events: none;
        display:none !important;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
</style>
```

[image]

**If you want display and hide all “Share” buttons in Document Library, you should copy the below CSS, and paste it to the script editor web part.**

```
<style>

#Ribbon\.Library\.Settings\.LibraryPermissions-Large,
#Ribbon\.Library\.Settings\.LibraryPermissions-Medium,
#Ribbon\.Library\.Settings\.LibraryPermissions-Small,
#Ribbon\.Documents\.Manage\.ManagePermissions-Medium,
#Ribbon\.Documents\.Share\.ShareItem-Large,
.js-listview-qcbShareButton,
.ms-calloutLink[title="Share file or folder with other person or group"],
.ms-contextmenu-link[title="Shared With"] {
    pointer-events: none;
        display:none !important;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

</style>
```

Reference:

- [How to disable Share in SharePoint Document Library?](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/disable-share-in-sharepoint-document-library/)